# How to do this complex query in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as totalvotes FROM votes WHERE option_id IN(SELECT id FROM options WHERE ques_id='$poll_id')");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT options.id, options.value, COUNT(*) as votes FROM votes, options WHERE votes.option_id=options.id AND votes.option_id IN(SELECT id FROM options WHERE ques_id='$poll_id') GROUP BY votes.option_id");
```

Comment: Reading the [docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html)?

Comment: You should add more details to your question, such as exactly what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what behavior you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

*Assume your query is correct*

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as totalvotes FROM votes WHERE option_id IN(SELECT id FROM options WHERE ques_id='$poll_id')");
```

**ANSWER**

```
        $result = $this->db->select('count(*) AS totalvotes')
                ->from('votes')
                ->where("option_id IN(SELECT id FROM options WHERE ques_id='$poll_id')");
```

---

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT options.id, options.value, COUNT(*) as votes FROM votes, options WHERE votes.option_id=options.id AND votes.option_id IN(SELECT id FROM options WHERE ques_id='$poll_id') GROUP BY votes.option_id");
```

**ANSWER**

```
        $result = $this->db->select('options.id, options.value, COUNT(*) as votes')
                ->from('votes v')
                ->join('options o', 'v.option_id=o.options.id')
                ->where("v.option_id IN(SELECT id FROM v.options WHERE v.ques_id='$poll_id')")
                ->group_by('v.option_id);
```